Safari scroll jump after unloading element innerHTML
This issue is isolated to Safari on macOS and iOS. All other browsers don't have this problem.
I have an Intersection Observer that handles loading/unloading chapters in a vertical scrolling book.
This function unloads chapters that aren't in view:
function unloadChapter(chapterId) {

  const chapterElement = document.querySelector('.chapter[data-chapter-id="' + chapterId + '"] .chapter-content');

  if (chapterElement) {
    chapterElement.innerHTML = '';
  }
}

When unloading a chapter below the current position, there's no scroll jank.
But when unloading a chapter above the current chapter, the scroll position jumps due to the sudden unload of content, but only on Safari.
I have a temporary work around by adding back in the difference of lost content height, then scrolling back to the new relative position:
function unloadChapter(chapterId) {

    const chapterElement = document.querySelector('.chapter[data-chapter-id="' + chapterId + '"] .chapter-content');

    if (chapterElement) {
        // Measure the current scroll height
        const previousScrollHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
        
        // Measure the current scroll position
        const previousScrollTop = window.scrollY || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    
        // Unload the chapter content
        chapterElement.innerHTML = '';

        // Measure the new scroll height after unloading the content
        const newScrollHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;

        // Calculate the difference in scroll height
        const scrollHeightDifference = previousScrollHeight - newScrollHeight;

        // Adjust the scroll position based on the difference in height
        window.scrollTo(0, previousScrollTop - scrollHeightDifference);
    }
}

But this causes a noticeable flicker when scrolling, and doesn't work correctly when scrolling up to previous chapters.
Edit:
Not a solution to the original issue, though I've resolved my particular situation by setting the minHeight of the unloaded chapter to the height before unload. This works mostly well, with some quirks.
